# How to close bootstrap warning alert on mouse click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

[Image when 'x' is not clicked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDNdJ.png)
I have a website that contains bootstrap warning alerts. The warning box appears when user selects a carrier on the drop down carrier. When the box appears user has to click on the 'x' for the box to disappear, otherwise, if user does not click the 'x' and selects a different carrier another warning box appears just like in the image. I'm trying to make it disappear if user clicks anywhere on the page or when user clicks on the 'x'.

HomeConroller.cs

```
   warning = ("<div class=\"alert alert-warning alert-dismissible\" role=\"alert\">
  <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button><strong>" +
   warning + "</strong></div>");
```

Index.cshtml //Need help on this part of the file to work when user clicks anywhere on page and notification disappear.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").click(function () {
        $(".alert").alert("close");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the alert when the select field is changed not when someone clicks on the content

Or when the user selects a new carrier you can check if there are no open alerts , if so the add a new one.

```
if($(".alert").length == 0) {
    //add new alert 
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  $("#carrier").change(function(){
     //Close all open alerts
     $(".alert").alert("close");
     //Add new alert here
  });
});
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
   
    <select id="carrier">
      <option value="verizon">Verizon</option>
      <option value="tmobile">TMobile</option>
      <option value="at&t">AT & T</option>
      <option value="sprint">Sprint</option>
    </select>

    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
      <strong>Warning!</strong>
 Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
    </div>
```